# Creating a JLabel with a Gradient

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, graphics2d

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to create a heading using a JLabel and for its fill to be a gradient. I cannot get it to work and I've been trying for a while. I've been grabbing bits of come from here and other websites and cannot seem to make this work, nor make sense of other peoples more complex code that does work. Here are my two classes so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().setupGUI();
    }
    public void setupGUI() {
        //set up frames and buttons etc.
            JFrame theFrame = new JFrame ("Crystal Ball");
            theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel background = new JPanel();
            background.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            background.setLayout(new BoxLayout(background, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
            theFrame.setSize(500,1000);
            DLabel heading = new DLabel("Guess a Number");
            heading.setText("GUESS A NUMBER");
            heading.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(theFrame.getWidth(),100));
            heading.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40));
            heading.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            //heading.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            heading.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
            background.add(heading);
            theFrame.getContentPane().add(background);
            theFrame.pack();
            theFrame.setVisible(true);
            //startGame();
        }
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class DLabel extends JLabel
{

    Dimension size = new Dimension(70, 80);

    public DLabel(String name)
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(size);
        this.setText(name);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(TOP, Color.white, Color.black));
        this.setOpaque(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      // super.paintComponent(g);  // *** commented
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      Color color1 = Color.YELLOW;
      Color color2 = color1.brighter();
      int w = getWidth();
      int h = getHeight();
      GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
      g2d.setPaint(gp);
      g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
      super.paintComponent(g); // *** added
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one little "trick" you can actually do, by leaving the label transparent, you can actually paint under the text by painting BEFORE you call `super.paintComponent`, for example...

[image: Raindbow]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLabel101 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLabel101();
    }

    public TestLabel101() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JLabel {

        public TestPane() {
            setText("Happy, Happy");
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                    new Point(0, 0), 
                    new Point(0, getHeight()), 
                    new float[]{0.142f, 0.284f, 0.426f, 0.568f, 0.71f, 0.852f, 1f}, 
                    new Color[]{Color.PINK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.RED});
            g2d.setPaint(lgp);
            g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
            g2d.dispose();
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    }

}
```

*nb: I should point out that this process is inefficient, as the `RepaintManager` will still want to paint under the component*

There is another trick, but my two year old daughter wants to check to see if Santa is here ;)

**Updated**

The other trick involves understanding how the paint process actually works.  When you call `super.paintComponent`, it calls the `update` method on the `ComponentUI` (look and feel delegate), this is actually the method that fills the background if the component is opaque, this method then calls the look and feels delegate's `paint` method, which actually does the base painting...

We can circumvent the process slightly and instead of calling `super.paintComponent`, we can call the look and feels delegate's `paint` method directly...

```
public class TestPane extends JLabel {

    public TestPane() {
        setText("Happy, Happy");
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                new Point(0, 0), 
                new Point(0, getHeight()), 
                new float[]{0.142f, 0.284f, 0.426f, 0.568f, 0.71f, 0.852f, 1f}, 
                new Color[]{Color.PINK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.RED});
        g2d.setPaint(lgp);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
        g2d.dispose();
        getUI().paint(g, this);
    }

}
```

This is more efficient then the previous example, as it doesn't require the `RepaintManager` to paint the area underneath this component, but it might not work with all look and feels

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you made the JLabel opaque, which means it will paint the background. So the call to super.paintComponent(...) over paints the gradient background. So get rid of:

```
//this.setOpaque(true);
```

Another problem with the code is that color1.brighter() doesn't work. Try something like:

```
  Color color2 = Color.RED;
```

Also, You should not change the Graphics object, since that object is also used to paint other Swing components. Instead you should use `g.create()` to get a copy of the Graphics object. Make your changes to that object, do the painting and then `dispose()` the object.

So the (untested) code would be something like:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
...
g2d.fillRect(...);
g2d.dispose();

super.paintCompoenent(g);
```

Comment: Thanks really gave me some understanding, merry christmas!

Answer (score 2):

You should set your gradientPaint object to your Graphics and then pass that into super.paintComponent

try this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      Color color1 = Color.YELLOW;
      Color color2 = color1.brighter();
      int w = getWidth();
      int h = getHeight();
      GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
      g2d.setPaint(gp);
      super.paintComponent(g2d);
    }
```

Comment: plus one, but super.paintComponent(g2d); as last code line is important (for example) for painting text in JButton correctly

Comment: It's also possible that other look and feels could change the current "paint" state, there by overriding your settings...

Comment: You should not change the Graphics object, since that object is also used to paint other Swing components. Instead you should use `g.create()` to get a copy of the Graphics object. Make your changes to that object. Also you should then `dispose()` the object after the super.paintComponent() call.

Comment: Does that work for you? Cause for me the label is still grey.

Comment: @quantum285, you would also need to make the label non-opaque (the default, so get rid of your statement that makes it opaque), so that the call to super.paintComponent() doesn't repaint over the gradient background.

Comment: @camickr The OP made the label opaque, so I took that as stated ;)

Comment: @camickr you commented here more that is standard for your answers here, can you please to post that in the answer ....

Comment: @mKorbel, actually you are right. The suggestion here won't help since the g2d object is the same object as the g object so it doesn't matter which one you pass to the super.paintComponent().

Comment: Really appreciate the help guys but now I'm just getting a transparent JLabel.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/GradientLabel.html this may be help you.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, it would seem that while opaque, the look and feel is overriding the `paint` property when it fills the background of the component...

Comment: It works for me! Got rid of the opaque line and the order I'm using is setPaint, fillRect, paintComponent and dispose.