# How can I render an arc with a 3 color gradient?

Tags: java, swing, gradient, paintcomponent

I'm trying to render an arc that starts off as green, transitions to yellow, and finally to red. Right now it just transitions from green to red using the standard GradientPaint method. Is there a way to do it with 3 colors?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    BasicStroke wideStroke = new BasicStroke(24.0f);
    g.setStroke(wideStroke);

    g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(new Point(10, 140), Color.GREEN, new Point(100, 10), Color.RED));  

    g.draw(new Arc2D.Double(25, 25, 200, 200, 180, -90, Arc2D.OPEN));   
}
```

Comment: You could use a [`LinearGradientPaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/LinearGradientPaint.html) which allows for multiple colours (and points), [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037321/no-repaint-while-resizing-when-using-setpaintgradient/12038987#12038987) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349038/java-swing-rainbow-border-for-a-jcomponent/44349617#44349617) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27641641/creating-a-jlabel-with-a-gradient/27641940#27641940)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MadProgrammer

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    BasicStroke wideStroke = new BasicStroke(24.0f);
    g.setStroke(wideStroke);

    LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
            new Point2D.Float(0, 160),
            new Point2D.Float(160, 0),
            new float[] {0f, 0.5f, 1f},
            new Color[] {Color.green, Color.yellow, Color.red}
            );

    g.setPaint(lgp);

    g.draw(new Arc2D.Double(25, 25, 200, 200, 180, -90, Arc2D.OPEN));
}
```